# Telerik: ajax request complete event

Tags: telerik-grid

What is the name of the ajax complete event in Telerik Rad Grid? I tried what is in the documentation but I get following error

```
Parser Error Message: Type 'Telerik.Web.UI.GridClientEvents' does not have a public property named 'OnResponseEnd'.

Source Error:

Line 62:     EditMode="EditForms" GridLines="None" Visible="true" OnNeedDataSource="ctlBenefitLimitsGrid_NeedDataSource">
Line 63:     <ClientSettings>
Line 64:         <ClientEvents OnResponseEnd = "ctlBenefitLimitsGrid_RequestEnd"></ClientEvents>
Line 65:     </ClientSettings>
Line 66:     <MasterTableView Width="100%" Summary="RadGrid table" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify an OnResponseEnd method in JavaScript to run when a response is completed:

```
<ClientEvents OnRequestStart="RequestStart" OnResponseEnd="ResponseEnd" />
```

---

Edit:
My fault, in the newer version, it's been moved.
Try adding it to your RadAjaxManager or RadAjaxManagerProxy.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
   <ClientEvents OnResponseEnd="responseEnd" />
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajxonresponseend.html

Comment: @Ed B: Unfortunatelly, I do not have access to AjaxManager, only to proxy, which for some reason does not expose ClientEvents at all